# Flutter Provider.of and search

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am a beginner in flutter and app development. I have a problem. I am using `Provider.of` in order to get my data. I am getting data and showing it in `ListView.builder` with no problem. But I want to make a search on my list.

Please refer to code below

```
     class RecipeList extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _RecipeListState createState() => _RecipeListState();
    
    }
    
        class _RecipeListState extends State<RecipeList> {
        
          List<Recipe>showList =List();//creating my list of searched data
        
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
          //getting my recipe list in order to show them
          final recipes = Provider.of<List<Recipe>>(context);
           showList=recipes;
  

final user = Provider.of<User>(context);


         
        
            String _image;
            Widget myImage(int index,)
            {
              if(recipes[index].image == ''){
                return Image.asset('images/no_image.jpg');
              }
              else{
                return
        
                  FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 250,
                    placeholder: 'images/loading.webp',
                    image: recipes[index].image,
                  );
              }
    
        }
    
        return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
          stream:DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
          builder: (context,snapshot){
    
              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                UserData userdata = snapshot.data;
    
                if (userdata.is_admin == true) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topRight,
                            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            colors: [Colors.blue[200], Colors.orange[100]])),
                    child: Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                         
                          title: Text('Recipes'),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          elevation: 0,
    
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        body: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[



                        Material(
                              elevation: 0,
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: TextField(
   



                            onChanged: (val) {
                              val = val.toLowerCase();
    
                                  setState(() {
                                    showList = recipes.where((recipe){
                                      var title = recipe.name.toLowerCase();
                                      return title.contains(val);
                                    }).toList();
    
                                  });
                                },
    
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Search",
                                    hintText: "Search",
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(25.0)))),
                              ),),
                            SizedBox(height: 15,),
                            Expanded(

                            

                 child: ListView.builder(
    
                                  shrinkWrap: true,

                                  itemCount: showList.length,
    
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    
                                    if (recipes[index].image == null) {
                                      String _image = 'images/new.png';
                                    }
                                    else {
                                      _image = recipes[index].image;
                                    }
                                    //   print(recipes[index].image);
    
                                    return Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SlimyCard(
                                          color: Colors.teal[200],
                                          width: 300,
                                          topCardHeight: 350,
                                          bottomCardHeight: 300,
                                          borderRadius: 15,
                                          topCardWidget: Column(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Text(recipes[index].name[0]
                                                  .toUpperCase() +
                                                  recipes[index].name.substring(1),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 35,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                ),),
    
                                              ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                  .circular(25.0),
    
    
                                                  child: myImage(index)
    
    
                                              ),
                                              // Image.network('https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/recipe-collections/collection-image/2013/05/chorizo-mozarella-gnocchi-bake-cropped.jpg')),
    
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          bottomCardWidget: SingleChildScrollView(
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                Text('Ingredients',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
    
                                                      fontSize: 25,
                                                      color: Colors.white
                                                  ),),
                                                SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                                Text(recipes[index].ingredients,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 16
                                                  ),),
                                                SizedBox(height: 20,),
    
                                                Text('Recipe',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 25
                                                      ,
                                                      color: Colors.white
                                                  ),),
                                                SizedBox(height: 5,),
    
                                                Text(recipes[index].recipe,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 16
                                                  ),),
                                                RaisedButton(
    
    
                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                        .circular(7.0),
                                                    //side: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange)
                                                  ),
                                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                      233, 217, 108, 1),
                                                  onPressed: () async {
                                                    final CollectionReference recipecollection = Firestore
                                                        .instance.collection(
                                                        'recipe');
                                                    await recipecollection.document(
                                                        recipes[index].id).delete();
                                                    StorageReference firestoreStorageref = await FirebaseStorage
                                                        .instance
                                                        .getReferenceFromUrl(
                                                        recipes[index].image);
                                                    firestoreStorageref.delete();
                                                  },
    
                                                  child: Text(
                                                      'Delete'
                                                  ),
                                                )
    
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          slimeEnabled: false,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 25,)
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
    
                                )),
                          ],
                        )
    
                    ),
                  );
                }
```

1. I want to show this list on the search and modify it. first I fill it with data from the provider.
2. I have created a TextField for Search the `onChanged` method filters the typed value and returns a list. When I print in `onChanged` function it is working.
3. I am showing my list with `ListView`, when I print the size of `showList` in `onChanged` function, it filters and gives the right value but when I use it for itemCount it never changes

Comment: Hey, formatting your post properly would make it much more digestible.

Comment: I did it,sorry that I did not do it properly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `searchable_dropdown` instead of the `TextField`. You can assign the list to it and it will search the list based on the to string method so you have to override it.

Refer the link to the dependency: https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown.